# how to find span tag iside iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am using TinyMCE editor that resides inside an iframe. There is a span having class AMedit inside this iframe. The id of this iframe is elm1_ifr. How can I find the span tag having class AMedit in this Iframe in jquery ? I have to do some stuff in this span once I find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#elm1_ifr").contents().find("span.AMedit ");
```

To attach a focus event listener on that contenteditable span you can use this:

```
var span = $("#elm1_ifr").contents().find("span.AMedit ");
span.on('focus',function(){
   //your code here
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wcewt/) (check the console)

Comment: Ok how can I use the focus event of this span now ? Please alert something on the focus event of this span. Thanks

Comment: @user2702406, focus event is for input fields. Do you have a input inside the span?

Comment: this span is editable having attribute contenteditable = true

Comment: @user2702406, do you have access to the iFrame? you could fire it inside the iframe with `$(document).on('focus', 'span[contenteditable]', function () {`

Comment: yes iframe is on the same domain. I have used as:

var iFrame = $("#elm1_ifr").contents().find("span.AMedit");


when I alert iFrame, it alerts [objectObject],How can I get the focus event of this span class now ??

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $("#elm1_ifr span").hasClass("AMedit") )
{
  // your code
};
else
{
  //your code
}
```